# How do I see how many check boxes I have checked in Java script?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I tried this code but it just doesn't work

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function chck(){
    var counter=0;
    var y=document.getElementsByName(cmmn);
    var chckdBoxes=[];
        for(var x=0; x<checkboxes.length; x++){
        if(y[x].checked){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    alert(counter);
}
</script>
```

Comment: The code is incomplete

Comment: Show also the `html` code where you have the checkboxes and any other relevant information.

Comment: What's `cmmn`? What's `checkboxes`? Neither of these are declared or set by the code.

Comment: already answered many times in stackoverflow anyways this is the link from 1 of the answer http://jsfiddle.net/ZjK3w/129/

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
var counter = 0;
var aa = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
    if (aa[i].type == 'checkbox') 
        if (aa[i].checked) { // if (aa[i].checked == true) {
            counter++;
        }
}
```

Comment: `if(aa[i].checked == true)` is just a long-winded way of writing `if(aa[i].checked)`. In any case, for a *useful* answer, say *what* you changed, and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like below, filter the NodeList then get the length.

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('foo[]');
var checked_count = [].filter.call(checkboxes, function(e) {return e.checked;}).length;
```

**[THE JSFIDDLE DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/KNh7R/)**

Or if you use jQuery, then it could be:

```
var checked_count = $("[name='foo[]']:checked").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=0;
$('input').each(function(){

    var ty = ""+$(this).attr('type');
    if(ty == "checkbox")
    {
        i++;        
    }    
});
alert(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can add pseudo-selector:

```
$(':checked')
```